# Jasper-report: Crosstab

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a report in iReport-jasper-reports.

**How to create a line numbering in crosstab?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add field COUNT in **query**.
Or Count column in Jasper **report**.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's possible that there is an alternate, however I managed to do this only with the approach that I want to describe in this short article.

Crosstabs have a variable called ROW_COUNT

Two aspects to note:

- The variable counts logical crosstab rows and not layout rows. That
  is, if the crosstab has columns that exceed the element width and
  rows break into several chunks, you will see the same row number for
  the layout rows that make up a single logical row.
- Total rows are not counted, only detail rows.

Please looked into following article for more details
https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-introduce-row-numbers-cross-tab